# MsSql Merge not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005, merge

I'm trying to preform a merge but for some reason i get a error.

What I'm doing is: I am insert all the records where the `productname` is not empty and it is not marked as double in a temp table.

After I loop through temp table to insert/update every record in the real table `[Products]`

```
MERGE INTO [Products] AS T
USING SingleProducts AS S
ON (T.SoftwareID = S.[@ProductCode] AND T.PriceType = S.[@PriceType])
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT (SoftwareID, IsActive, [Image], ProductNameNL, ProductNameFR, DescriptionNL, DescriptionFR, UnitPrice, PriceType, CreationDate, LastUpdatedDate)
        VALUES (S.[@ProductCode], 0, 'no-image.png', S.[@ProductNameNL], S.[@ProductNameFR], S.[@DescriptionNL], S.[@DescriptionFR], 
                    S.[@UnitPrice], S.[@PriceType], S.[@CreationDate], GETDATE())
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET
        T.[SoftwareID] = S.[@ProductCode],
        T.[ProductNameNL] = S.[@ProductNameNL],
        T.[ProductNameFR] = S.[@ProductNameFR],
        T.[DescriptionNL] = S.[@DescriptionNL],
        T.[DescriptionFR] = S.[@DescriptionFR],
        T.[UnitPrice] = S.[@UnitPrice],
        T.[PriceType] = S.[@PriceType]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
    THEN DELETE
OUTPUT $action, inserted.*, deleted.*;
```

Comment: What is the error? Please post it/

Comment: Do have column Name in source table named as @ProductCode, @PriceType?

Comment: Ow, This is the error: Msg 325, Level 15, State 1, Procedure CopySingleProducts, Line 41
Incorrect syntax near 'MERGE'. You may need to set the compatibility level of the current database to a higher value to enable this feature. See help for the SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL option of ALTER DATABASE.

Comment: The problem is im on sql 2005 where i can't use the merge as far as i seen it

Comment: @Teckniel MERGE is in 2008 and higher. You'll have write your own code to mimic.